# Correct way to deprecate parameter alias in click

Tags: python, python-click

I want to deprecate a parameter alias in `click` (say, switch from underscores to dashes). For a while, I want both formulations to be valid, but throw a `FutureWarning` when the parameter is invoked with the to-be-deprecated alias. However, I have not found a way to access the actual alias a parameter was invoked with.

In short, I want:

```
click.command()
click.option('--old', '--new')
def cli(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

to raise a warning when the option is invoked with `--old`, but not when it is invoked with `--new`. Is there a clean way to do this that doesn't rely too much on undocumented behavior?

I tried adding a callback to the `click.option`, but it seems to be called after the option is parsed, and the arguments contain no information which alias was actually used. A solution would probably overload `click.Option` or even `click.Command`, but I don't know where the actual parsing takes place.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't rely too much on undocumented behavior*?

Comment: Something that probably still works in the next release.

Comment: So a small monkey patch on a file that hasn't changed in 4 years would meet that desire?

Comment: Well, the ideal answer would do without that, but if that's the best we can get it would be okay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to know what option name was used to select a a particular option, I suggest you monkey patch the option parser using some custom classes.  This solution ends up inheriting from both `click.Option` and `click.Command`:

#### Code:

```
import click
import warnings

class DeprecatedOption(click.Option):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.deprecated = kwargs.pop('deprecated', ())
        self.preferred = kwargs.pop('preferred', args[0][-1])
        super(DeprecatedOption, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class DeprecatedOptionsCommand(click.Command):

    def make_parser(self, ctx):
        """Hook 'make_parser' and during processing check the name
            used to invoke the option to see if it is preferred"""

        parser = super(DeprecatedOptionsCommand, self).make_parser(ctx)

        # get the parser options
        options = set(parser._short_opt.values())
        options |= set(parser._long_opt.values())

        for option in options:
            if not isinstance(option.obj, DeprecatedOption):
                continue

            def make_process(an_option):
                """ Construct a closure to the parser option processor """

                orig_process = an_option.process
                deprecated = getattr(an_option.obj, 'deprecated', None)
                preferred = getattr(an_option.obj, 'preferred', None)
                msg = "Expected `deprecated` value for `{}`"
                assert deprecated is not None, msg.format(an_option.obj.name)

                def process(value, state):
                    """The function above us on the stack used 'opt' to
                        pick option from a dict, see if it is deprecated """

                    # reach up the stack and get 'opt'
                    import inspect
                    frame = inspect.currentframe()
                    try:
                        opt = frame.f_back.f_locals.get('opt')
                    finally:
                        del frame

                    if opt in deprecated:
                        msg = "'{}' has been deprecated, use '{}'"
                        warnings.warn(msg.format(opt, preferred),
                                      FutureWarning)

                    return orig_process(value, state)

                return process

            option.process = make_process(option)

        return parser
```

#### Using the Custom Classes:

First add a `cls` parameter to `@click.command` like:

```
@click.command(cls=DeprecatedOptionsCommand)
```

Then for each option which has deprecated values add the `cls` and `deprecated` values like:

```
@click.option('--old1', '--new1', cls=DeprecatedOption, deprecated=['--old1'])
```

And optionally you can add a `preferred` value like:

```
@click.option('--old2', '-x', '--new2', cls=DeprecatedOption,
              deprecated=['--old2'], preferred='-x')
```

#### How does this work?

There are two custom classes here, they derive from two `click` classes.  A custom `click.Command` and `click.Option`.
This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.command()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Command` object but allows this behavior to be over-ridden with the `cls` parameter. `@click.option()` works similarly. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` and `click.Option` in our own classes and over ride the desired methods.

In the case of the custom `click.Option`: `DeprecatedOption`, we add two new keyword attributes: `deprecated` and `preferred`.  `deprecated` is required and is a list of command names that will be warned about. `preferred` is optional, and specifies the recommended command name.  It is a string and will default to the last command name in the option line.

In the case of the custom `click.Command`: `DeprecatedOptionsCommand`, we override the `make_parser()` method.  This allows us to monkey patch the option parser instances in the parser instance.  The parser is not really intended for expansion like `Command` and `Option` so we have to get a little more creative.

In this case all option processing in the parser goes through the `process()` method.  Here we monkey patch that method, and in the patched method we look up one level in the stack frame to find the `opt` variable which is the name used to find the option.  Then, if this value is in the `deprecated` list, we issue the warning.

This code reaches into some *private* structures in the parser, but this is unlikely to be an issue.  This parser code was last changed 4 years ago.  The parser code is unlikely to undergo significant revisions.

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command(cls=DeprecatedOptionsCommand)
@click.option('--old1', '--new1', cls=DeprecatedOption,
              deprecated=['--old1'])
@click.option('--old2', '-x', '--new2', cls=DeprecatedOption,
              deprecated=['--old2'], preferred='-x')
def cli(**kwargs):
    click.echo("{}".format(kwargs))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '--old1 5',
        '--new1 6',
        '--old2 7',
        '--new2 8',
        '-x 9',
        '',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> --old1 5
{'new1': '5', 'new2': None}
C:/Users/stephen/Documents/src/testcode/test.py:71: FutureWarning: '--old1' has been deprecated, use '--new1'
  FutureWarning)
-----------
> --new1 6
{'new1': '6', 'new2': None}
-----------
> --old2 7
{'new2': '7', 'new1': None}
C:/Users/stephen/Documents/src/testcode/test.py:71: FutureWarning: '--old2' has been deprecated, use '-x'
  FutureWarning)
-----------
> --new2 8
{'new2': '8', 'new1': None}
-----------
> -x 9
{'new2': '9', 'new1': None}
-----------
> 
{'new1': None, 'new2': None}
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --old1, --new1 TEXT
  -x, --old2, --new2 TEXT
  --help                   Show this message and exit.
```