# Rename click option with keeping backward compatibility

Tags: python, python-click

I have option "device", which I would like to replace by "family" option, but I would like to keep the backward compatibility.
So if user uses "device" option, it will work, but throw some warning and "device" option will not be displayed in help any more. Instead "family" option will be displayed.
Here is the code:

```
FC = TypeVar("FC", bound=Union[Callable[..., Any], click.Command])
def device_options(options: FC) -> FC:
    """Setup options for device."""
    options = click.option(
        "-d",
        "--device",
        type=click.Choice(STH.devices()),
        help="Specify the device",
        required=True,
    )(options)
    return options
```

There is more device options in the function originally, but only one relevant was put here.
I know that for click group, it is possible to create alias for click group extension. But is there something similar for click option?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Based on click documentation, I tried:

```
"--device/--family",
```

and got:

```
raise TypeError("Secondary flag is not valid for non-boolean flag.")
TypeError: Secondary flag is not valid for non-boolean flag.
```

Comment: This question seems like it may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366719/correct-way-to-deprecate-parameter-alias-in-click

Comment: Unfortunately, this will no help, because option takes parameter...